How to read Apache HTTP Headers using PHP
How can I read these Apache HTTP Headers using PHP before they're sent to the client's browser?
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Sun, 09 Jul 2023 09:41:38 GMT
Expires: Mon, 10 Jul 2023 07:20:55 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Date: Mon, 10 Jul 2023 07:20:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2561


Apache may direct requests to be handled by PHP or handle others on its own. PHP can't do anything to requests that Apache handles on its own which is what appears to be the case here because those headers would only be present in a PHP response if you had set them in your code

@apokryfos I'm trying to read these values using PHP. Is that possible?

It's not straight forward but you can possibly use mod_ext_filter to call a PHP script to process any Apache response before it is sent. This is for the case where the request is not handled by PHP (e.g. it's a static file). You can also possibly just alter the headers using this without needing to run any script

I think headers-list() should be enough.

Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here? Why do you need access to those values?

What headers you can read depend on what server API you use to run PHP (mod_php, php-fpm...) and whether you have additional modules adding or editing headers after PHP finishes processing.

It is only possible to read headers sent by PHP, not the ones created by Apache settings.
Raw PHP provides headers_list() and headers_sent() for inspection of headers sending to client.

headers_list() will return a list of headers to be sent to the browser / client.
headers_sent() Checks if or where headers have been sent.

However, I think the best practice nowadays is to use PHP frameworks that supports PSR-7's ResponseInterface as output instead of doing straightforward echo and header() calls.
If you're using such framework, instead you'd create and accumulate the response object that implements ResponseInterface methods. You may then, at any point, simply use it's getHeaders() method to get previously set output headers.
Unless your needs are very trivial, I'd suggest using modern PHP frameworks for development.

You don't have full control over this entire list, and different parts of your stack control these values. Some of these are only determined after your script is done (for example your webserver).
You can set many of them with header(). But the short answer is that there's no one place where you can read these.
